# Datagrid and column count

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` linked to a `DataTable`.

To this DataGrid I add by myself 3 columns in the code behind.

```
if (resultDataGrid.ItemsSource != null)
            {
                List<String> resColList = new List<String> { "Solde M.O", "Solde Deplacement", "Solde Pieces" };

                foreach (string cName in resColList)
                {
                    DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();
                    column.Header = cName.ToUpper();
                    column.Binding = new Binding(cName.ToUpper());
                    resultDataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
                }
            }
```

I wanted to re-index the columns of this `DataGrid` who contains 19 columns but the problem is that when I do a count on my `DataGrid` columns it count only the 3 columns added in the code behind even if my `DataGrid` got my `DataTable` as `ItemSource`.

```
 if (_tableCase.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                resultDataGrid.ItemsSource = _tableCase.AsDataView();
                createResultColumn();
                setColumnIndex(); //This is the fonction which set the new index.
            }
            else
                resultDataGrid.ItemsSource = null;

            MessageBox.Show(resultDataGrid.Columns.Count.ToString()); //this return 3 first run and then 31 if I change the filter.

 for (int i = 0; i < resultDataGrid.Columns.Count; ++i) // Only display the 3 column added in the code behind.
                MessageBox.Show(resultDataGrid.Columns[i].Header.ToString());
```

but when in my application I'm changing the filter that display the rows from `DataTable` in the `DataGrid`, now my column count returns 31.

Anyone got any explanation about what I missed ? Because after hours of debuging nothing cames out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) states:

```
Automatically generated columns are not added to the Columns collection.
```

So this is a normal behaviour.

Comment: Strange. The documentation link you are referring is the docs for `System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid`, OP is asking for wpf one which is in `System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid`. In wpf columns are added to the Columns collection. Your answer is very wrong.